# Issue in Printing data from a hash table in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to process the data in a single file . i have to read the file and create a hash structure,get the value of fruitname append it to fruitCount and fruitValue and delete the line fruitName and write the entire output after the change is done.Given below is the content of file.

```
 # this is a new file
{
date 14/07/2016
time 11:15
end 11:20
total 30
No    "FRUITS"
Fruit_class
    {
    Name    "fruit 1"
    fruitName    "apple.fru"
    fruitId    "0"
    fruitCount    5
    fruitValue    6
    }
{
        Name    "fruit 2"
        fruitName       "orange.fru"
        fruitId "1"
        fruitCount      10
        fruitValue      20
        }
}
```

I tried with following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash_table;
my $name;
my $file = '/tmp/fruitdir/fruit1.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^\s*fruitName/) {
        ($name) = /(\".+\")/;
        next;
   }
   s/(fruitCount|fruitValue)/$name\.$1/;
   my ($key, $value) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
   $hash_table{$key} = $value;
}
print Dumper(\%hash_table);
```

This is not working . I need to append the value of fruitname and print the the entire file content as output. Any help will be appreciated.Given below is the output that i got.

```
$VAR1 = {
          '' => undef,
          'time' => '11:15    ',
          'date' => '14/07/2016',
          '{' => undef,
          '#' => 'this is a new file',
          'total' => '30    ',
          'end' => '11:20    ',
          'No' => '"FRUITS"',
          'Fruit_class' => undef,
          '}' => undef
        };
```

Expected hash as output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Name' => '"fruit 1"',
          'fruitId' => '"0"            ',
          '"apple_fru".fruitValue' => '6            ',
          '"apple_fru".fruitCount' => '5'

          'Name' => '"fruit 2"',
          'fruitId' => '"0"            ',
          '"orange_fru".fruitValue' => '10            ',
          '"orange_fru".fruitCount' => '20'


        };
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the hash table? If you only want to modify lines in the file, why do you need it?

Comment: Yes.Your query is absolutely valid. But my requirement demands me to use a hash table concept here. I have achieved output using shell script.But now its to be done with perl and hash concept. I am stuck with this :(

Comment: The your question is then really about reading the config (input) file into a hash? And then modify the hash, and then printing the hash to a file? In that case I would recommend using JSON instead of a custom made input file format. In this way modification becomes much easier, since there alread exists modules for reading and writing JSON.

Comment: Okay.Thank you. I will try. But may i know where am i doing mistake in the above code?Just curious to know.

Comment: You are welcome, and good luck! Regarding the output you show. I think there are many issues with the code. But one thing is why are the fruit information missing. I think it is because you split on white space, and the lines with fruit information starts with at least two spaces,  so maybe all these lines gets mapped to the line `'' => undef` in the output?

Comment: Could you provide the output that you are expecting?

Comment: @DiabJerius I have edited the post with the expected output. Pl check. Thanks

Comment: @DAN, I think we have a miscommunication.  I was asking for the output of the code that you presented.  It outputs a hash that isn't correct.  Please provide the hash that you would like to be printed.

Comment: @DiabJerius Apologies. Edited the post with expected hash to be printed. Thanks

Comment: @DAN, sorry for the delay, but that still isn't something that can be output.  You can't have the same key twice in a single hash.

Answer (score 2):

One word of advice before I continue:

> Document your code

There are several logic errors in your code which I think you would have recognized if you wrote down what you thought each line was supposed to do.  First, write down the algorithm that you would like to implement, then document how each step in the code implements a step in the algorithm.  At the end you'll be able to see what you missed, or what part is not working.

Here are the errors that I see

1. You aren't ignoring lines that you shouldn't be parsing.  For example, you're grabbing the '}' and '{' lines.
2. You aren't actually storing the name of the fruit.  You grab it, but immediately start the next loop without storing it.
3. You're not keeping track of each structure.  You need to start a new structure for each fruit.
4. Do you really want to keep the double quotes in the values?

Other things to worry about:

1. Are you guaranteed that the list of attributes is in that order?  For example, can `Name` come last?

Here's some code which does what I think you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash_table;
my $name;

my @fruit;

my $file = '/tmp/fruitdir/fruit1.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;

    # save hash table if there's a close bracket, but
    # only if it has been filled
    if ( /^\s*}\s*$/ ) {
        next unless keys %hash_table;

        # save COPY of hash table
        push @fruit, { %hash_table };

        # clear it out for the next iteration
        %hash_table = ();
    }

    # only parse lines that start with Name or fruit
    next unless
      my ( $key, $value ) =
      /^
         # skip any leading spaces
         \s*

         # parse a line beginning with Name or fruitXXXXX
         (
          Name
          |
          fruit[^\s]+
        )

        # need space between key and value
        \s+

        # everything that follows is a value. clean up
        # double quotes in post processing
        (.*)
     /x;

    # remove double quotes
    $value =~ s/"//g;

    if ( $key eq 'Name' ) {
        $name = $value;
    }
    else {
        $key = "${name}.${key}";
    }
   $hash_table{$key} = $value;
}

print Dumper \@fruit;
```

and here's the output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'fruit 1.fruitValue' => '6',
            'fruit 1.fruitName' => 'apple.fru',
            'Name' => 'fruit 1',
            'fruit 1.fruitCount' => '5',
            'fruit 1.fruitId' => '0'
          },
          {
            'fruit 2.fruitName' => 'orange.fru',
            'fruit 2.fruitId' => '1',
            'fruit 2.fruitCount' => '10',
            'fruit 2.fruitValue' => '20',
            'Name' => 'fruit 2'
          }
        ];
```